# What is wrong with my c# player jumping code ? (unity 3d)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I just started learning unity 3d, and I wrote c# code that makes my player jump but it is not working

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public float SideWaysForce = 500f;
bool CanJump;

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collisioninfo)
    {
        if (collisioninfo.collider.tag == "Ground")
        {
            Debug.Log("Can Jump");
            CanJump = true;
        }
        
        if (collisioninfo.collider.tag != "Ground")
        {
            Debug.Log("Can not Jump");
            CanJump = false;
        }
    }

void FixedUpdate()

if (CanJump == true && Input.GetKey("space"))
        {
             rb.AddForce(0, SideWaysForce * Time.deltaTime, 0);
        }
```

no error messages were shown in the Console

Answer (score 0):

Well, debug (with a debugger or with `Debug.Log`) if the script even works, then make sure both `CanJump` and `Input.GetKey("Space")` are true. Also, you probably should use `Input.GetKeyDown` if you don't want your character to fly when you're holding a key.

Comment: nothing changed. the player still can't jump

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure the player has a rigid body attached
2. Make sure the player has a Collider attached (eg. mesh collider)
3. Make sure the player has that script attached.
4. Make sure the RigidBody (rb) is assigned to the player's rigid body in inspector.
5. Make sure sideways force is the same value in the inspector and in the code (it should be 500f on both).
6. In Fixed Update you should have `Input.GetKey("Space")` not `Input.GetKey("space")` (I believe the capital letter matters).
7. Make sure your ground object has the "Ground" tag attached.

If non of these solutions fix your issue please tell me.

Comment: After I changed **Input.GetKey("space")** to  **Input.GetKey("Space")** a warning appeared and other keys didn't work anymore like A or D ( Side way movement)

**the warning** :  warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement

Comment: try: Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space); And if your using sideways movement with A and D then you should use Input.GetKey("A"); or Input.GetKey("D"); Alternatively you can use Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");